# How do I use connect Office 365 via MS Exchange to a GNOME Online Account?

Tags: online-accounts, ms-exchange, office365

I am trying to setup an online account that connects to my companies office365 but i'm getting the error: "Cannot fins WebDAV endpoint".
I can normally connect and login to the account via browser.
Do i need to install an additional connector to do this?

Answer (score 33):

Am I right in assuming that you are using gnome online accounts? I had a similar problem in other distros, and I was able to replicate it on an Ubuntu 17.10 virtual machine.

After clicking the new exchange account button in gnome online accounts, I typed in my email and password and submitted. The following screen came up. (I switched out my normal email address.) See photo below.

[image: Before]
<sup>**Before**</sup>

After changing the custom username field to be my entire email address and the server field to be "outlook.office365.com" (this server name may not apply to you; to find yours, look in the settings of your webmail page), the configuration succeeded, and ubuntu asked for my password again to add it to a keychain. See photo below.

[image: After]
<sup>**After**</sup>

Also, if you are using gnome evolution for your email, you may need to run the following command to install support for the exchange web server:

```
sudo apt install evolution-ews
```

Comment: This is not installed with LUbuntu...  have you a solution to connect as showed her over with lubuntu?

Comment: This is what I've been doing, and this is what has not been working.  Would love to see other answers!

Comment: This did the trick for my work account! Just had to make sure Custom > Username was an exact match of "Email" (including the org's domain) and that the server was set as described (it resets on each failure! IME).

Comment: Took me months of passive troubleshooting to do so until i stumbled upon this post, thanks!

Comment: don't forget to `sudo apt-get update -y` before trying to install evolution-ews.

Comment: Just a couple of hints, if this isn't enough:
    1. Try using outlook.com instead of outlook.office365.com.
    2. Use an app password instead of your main account password, expecially if you have 2fa activated. - If you dont know how to create an app password, check this ms guide - Note: this may be locked due to domain security setups.